# why does numpy int16 give 26 bytes memory space?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I want a fixed size (2 byte/16 bit) integer for further processing. But sys.getsizeof()prints a size of 26, I don't have anything larger or smaller than the max and min int16 can hold. Why is that, how can I fix it? Also when I changed int16 to int32, sys.getsizeof() prints 28 and int64 as 32.

```
def quantization_to_16_bit_int(float_list):
ratio = 2/65536
quantized_list = []
for i in range(len(float_list)):
    v = round(float_list[i]/ratio)
    quantized_list.append(v)
result = np.int16(quantized_list)
print(sys.getsizeof(result[0]))
return result
```

Comment: Is your list 13 elements long?

Comment: Instantiating a dtype is not the right way to create an array

Comment: Why are you looping like that instead of using numpy?

Comment: Nope I tested, the max is 32,767 and min -32,768 which are the largest and smallest values int16 can hold

Comment: I don't know what I should do.. I'm not very used to python...Can you please tell me the right way to do it?

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions, but ok. I can't tell you what to do because I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: My guess is that that is refcount + pointer to type object + pointer to shape object + actual data = 8 + 8 + 8 + 2 bytes

Comment: Wow that would make sense, because int32 comes out as 28, int64 as 32, which only differs in data size. But what are those things? are they actually stored in the list as well?

Comment: In a list, yes, in a numpy array, no, or to be more precise the array itself is a Python object with some overhead, but the actual elements are stored "C-style", so each would take only 2 bytes. Only once you access them one by one get they converted to Python objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the size of a wrapper object, not the size of an array element. The array elements are 2 bytes, not 26. You can see this by examining the array's [`itemsize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.itemsize.html#numpy.ndarray.itemsize) attribute.

`sys.getsizeof` is much harder to interpret than it would intuitively seem, and out of all the times a new programmer would be tempted to use it, it is almost never the right tool.